# Adding code templates in the PyCharm - is it possible?

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to add a new code template/snippet to PyCharm.

For example, I want to expand `lw` to `log.write_Line("|here is sould be cursor after code completition from snippet|")`.

Something like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_code_templates.htm .

But I didn't find such settings in PyCharm.

How to make it in PyCharm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found it - it's named Live Templates in PyCharm/IntellyJ Idea https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html